# Why is the vector dot product scaled?

Tags: vectors

I have scoured all the answers on this website but I still cannot understand why $a\cdot b = |a||b|\cos\theta$, if the dot product is interpreted as the amount of one vector, say $a$, in the same direction as the other, say $b$, then why do we scale it by multiplying it with the magnitude of the vector on which it projects? why do we need $|b|$?

Comment: Don't you like your products to be bilinear?

Comment: @AnginaSeng What does that mean? Sounds exciting for some reason lol

Comment: Sometimes it’s good to look for a proof of that result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand how the dot product is defined, it's better to first look at *why* the dot product is defined. The idea of the dot product is to have some operation which takes in two vectors (say $a$ and $b$), and returns a single (meaningful) value. As you suggest, if we were merely interested in the length of the projection of $a$ onto $b$ (or, as you put it, the amount of one vector goes in the same direction as the other), then we would indeed want to use $|a|\cos\theta$. But there are several problems with this ''definition''.

Indeed, let's say we did define such a product: say $a\star b=|a|\cos\theta$. Observe this ''product'' has the following problems:

- We do not have $a\star b=b\star a$. In other words, the product is not *commutative*.
- We do not have $a\star (b+c)=a\star b+a\star c$, it is not *distributive*.
- We do not have $a\star (xb)=x(a\star b)$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, it does not respect *scalar multiplication*.

That is why defining $a\cdot b=|a||b|\cos\theta$ is a much more natural definition. It satisfies the properties we want a usual product to satisfy, and hence tells us more about the vectors $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Yes, but what do you interpret that scalar value as then?

Comment: You could interpret it as the length of the projection of $a$ onto $b$, scaled by the length of $b$ itself.

Comment: And that scaling is important to preserve the properties that u mentioned

Comment: Exactly! That scaling is what allows us to have all of the above properties, and hence obtain a ''nice'' and useful mathematical tool.

Comment: Also, by the way, bilinear (as mentioned in the comments under your question) means that the second and third properties are satisfied (i.e. the dot product is _linear_ in both $a$ and $b$). Hope that helps!

Comment: Sweet man thanks!