# Why do we divide by the length squared when projecting a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, projection

So suppose we have two vectors $v$ and $w$. We want to project $w$ onto $v$.

To do so this method makes sense:
Make $v'$ just a vector in the same direction as $v$ with $\text{length} = 1$. Easily, $$v' = \frac{v}{\text{length} (v)} = \frac{v}{(v^T * v)^{.5}}$$

The denominator is the length because $(v^T * v)$ gives us the sum of each component squared, and then we take the square root of it.

So, $$\text{proj}_{v}(w) = (w v) * v'$$
The piece in the parenthesis gives us the length of $w$ onto vector $v$(because of dot product). Then the $v'$ gives us the direction. Are we taking the dot product of $(w v)$ with $v'$? If so, doesn't this just give us a number without a direction? If not, what operation are we doing with $(w v)$ and $v'$?

The following is what I keep reading online which also confuses me:
$$\text{proj}_{v}(w) = \frac{(vw)}{v^Tv}v$$

So the numerator is the same, right? It's telling us the length of $w$ along the vector $v$. The denominator is weird though. So $v^Tv$ should be the length of vector $v$ squared, right? Shouldn't we need to take the square root of $v^Tv$ to get the length. The length will then be used to make the $v$ outside of our fraction a unit length vector, but we have length squared in this case. Why is that?

Comment: Left side depends only on the direction of $v$, not on its length. On the right side we have two $v$'s in the numerator, one inside the inner product and one outside.  If we divide by the norm of $v$ the right side would depend in the length of $v$. We should divide it by the square of the norm so that the right side also does not depend on the length of $v$.

Comment: "The piece in the parentheses gives us the length of $w$ onto vector $v$" That would only be true if $v$ were a unit vector. But $v$ is not a unit vector.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a misunderstanding of the dot product. The dot product gives you the length of the projection of $ w $, **scaled** by the length of $ v $. You can see this by substituting the geometric formula of the dot product:

$$\ w \cdot v = \vert \vert w \vert \vert \ \vert \vert v \vert \vert \ \cos(\theta) $$

(You can see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3755042/why-is-the-vector-dot-product-scaled) for why the dot product is scaled.)

When finding the projected vector, we want to avoid the scaling, so we divide by $\ \vert \vert v \vert \vert $:

$$\ \frac{\vert \vert w \vert \vert \ \vert \vert v \vert \vert \ \cos(\theta)}{\vert \vert v \vert \vert}  $$

That will give us the length of the projected vector. We multiply that by the unit vector of $ v $, which is obtained from:

$$\ \frac{v}{\vert \vert v \vert \vert} $$

Putting them together, we have:

$$\ \frac{\vert \vert w \vert \vert \ \vert \vert v \vert \vert \ \cos(\theta)}{\vert \vert v \vert \vert} * \frac{v}{\vert \vert v \vert \vert} $$
$$\ = \frac{\vert \vert w \vert \vert \ \vert \vert v \vert \vert \ \cos(\theta)}{\vert \vert v \vert \vert * \vert \vert v \vert \vert} * v $$
$$\ = \frac{\vert \vert w \vert \vert \ \vert \vert v \vert \vert \ \cos(\theta)}{\vert \vert v \vert \vert^2} * v $$
$$\ = \frac{w \cdot v}{\vert \vert v \vert \vert^2} * v $$

You can see that we end up with the length squared in the denominator. In short, we divide by $ \vert \vert v \vert \vert $ once to get rid of the scaling from the dot product, and again to obtain a unit vector of $ v $.